# Wordpress ACF relationship not in sync

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have two custom post types "Departments" and "Employees" in which both I have added an custom field with the type of "relationship", so that I on the Departments page can see, which employees are assigned to the department and on the Employees page, I can see which department they are attached to.

So far it works but somehow, when I assign an employee to an department or vice versa, and I go to the department or employee page, the relationships has not been updated - is this a common issue? That doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

When you use relationship field, the link is only in one direction : if you link an employee to a department, you create a link employee->department, but not the reverse link department->employee.

Maybe this tutorial could help you to create a bidirectional relationship field :

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/bidirectional-relationships/